# AWS Amplify Deploy (Build & Test) React JS + Jest + Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, deployment, jestjs, aws-amplify

I've deployed a React JS project on AWS Amplify and everything ran ok. But I have some test scripts that I would like to run before Amplify deploy a new build at every deploy. The problem is when I  changed the `amplify.yml` to try running my test scripts before building the code now it doesn't finish building anymore (loading indefinetily without finishing building & deploy).

`amplify.yml` before changes:

```
version: 1
applications:
  - frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm ci
        build:
          commands:
            - npm run build
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: build
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
    appRoot: burger-builder
```

`amplify.yml` after changes:

```
version: 1
applications:
  - frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm ci
        build:
          commands:
            - npm run build
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: build
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
  - test:
      phases:
        preTest:
          commands:
            - npm ci
        test:
          commands:
            - npm run test
    appRoot: burger-builder
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `create-react-app` runs your Jest tests in interactive mode. To understand what that means, run `npm run test` in your terminal and note that you'll have to change some code or hit 'a' to actually run your tests. You don't want this behavior in your Amplify deploy process. In the amplify.yml file, run your tests in non-interactive mode with `npm test -- --watchAll=false`. Or with yarn, `yarn test --watchAll=false`.